# Document icon for attachement visible in MFMailComposeViewController in iOS6 but not iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I attach my own document type to mail using `addAttachmentData`. On iOS6 the `MFMailComposeViewController` uses a document icon (`large_document.png`) that I created to represent the attachment. On iOS5 there is just a blank white space where a document icon should be.

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:recipeData  mimeType:@"application/developiosapp" fileName:@"<filename>" ];
```

My Info.plist looks like this:

[image: plist]

Many Thanks!